# Python tkinter not showing gif image and appears as PhotoImage.1

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I'm doing a tic tac toe project for my intro to python class and I want to make a grid of 9 buttons so when you click on them an image of an x or a circle appears. My code functions properly without the images but it does't with images.

[Layout for tic tac toe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UODbJ.png)

[What happens after I click on one of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpXi9.png)

this is the code (sorry I never posted on stack so I don't know how to format)
This is the new one

```
def sink(self, i):

    if self.turn:
        me = PhotoImage(file="x.gif")
        self.turn = False
        self.bState[i] = -1
        self.bList[i].config(relief=SUNKEN, text=me, state='disabled')
    else:
        me = PhotoImage(file="o.gif")
        self.turn = True
        self.bState[i] = 1
        self.bList[i].config(relief=SUNKEN, text=me, state='disabled')
```

Comment: oh whoops I used the wrong code. I was in the middle of playing with the code before. I changed the text= widget to image= and now when I click on the buttons it turns into a really small box

Comment: If the old code isn't relevant, please remove it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're passing the image to the `text=` option of the buttons.  This option, as you might possibly guess from the name, only specifies text for the button.  Use the `image=` option instead.

The code still wouldn't work quite right, since you are storing the reference to the images you load only in a local variable - the image will vanish as soon as the function returns.  (The connection between a Tkinter widget and any image it displays is entirely outside of Python's worldview, and therefore isn't sufficient to keep the image from being garbage collected.)  You need to maintain a reference to each image that lives as long as the widget does - typically either an attribute of the widget, or a global variable.  Since you only have the two images to deal with here, global variables would make more sense than reloading an image from disk every time a move is made.

Comment: Oh thanks! I just looked back at my code and realized that I accidentally changed the image= widget to the text= widget. But even though that was one of the problems my buttons still won't turn into the images even with a reference